# How do i translate my swift datatype into a realm object

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have developed a little GPS tracking app in Swift which I started as a runtime project to build the parsing logic. I'm now wanting to store the data in Realm objects, but before i go through a refactoring process i wanted to understand whether i'm on the right path.

I currently have a class which has functions to manipulate itself and stores data, this doesn't seem to fit with the various realm models i've seen where by the data object is simply a store of data.

```
class SkiTrack: NSObject, ObservableObject {

    var speed = Speed()
    var altitude = Altitude()
    var distance = Distance()

    var startTime = Date()
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var locationList: [Location] = []

    private var counter = SkiTrackSegmentCounter()
    private var history = LocationHistory()

    var trackSegments: [SkiTrackSegment] = []
    var currentSegment: SkiTrackSegment
    var unknownLocations: [Location] = []

    var numberOfLifts: Int = 0
    var numberOfRuns: Int = 0

    override init() {
        self.currentSegment = SkiTrackSegment()

        super.init()

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
    }

    public func receiveUpdate(newLocation: CLLocation) {

        // Do some management of the location and use it to update data in the class
        return
    }


    private func parse(_ newLocation: CLLocation) -> Location {
        let locationInfo = self.history.getCurrentLocationType(speed: newLocation.speed, course: newLocation.course, altitude: newLocation.altitude)

        return Location(core: newLocation, altitudeChange: locationInfo.altitudeChange, type: locationInfo.locationType)

    }

    private func updateDataObjects(location: Location) {
        if let lastLocation = self.locationList.last?.core {

            let delta = location.core.distance(from: lastLocation)
            let isLiftDistance = location.type == .lift
            distance.update(Measurement(value: delta, unit: UnitLength.meters), isLift: isLiftDistance)
        }
        speed.update(location.core.speed)
        altitude.update(location.core.altitude)
    }

    private func clearLocations() {
        self.unknownLocations.removeAll()
    }

}

// MARK: Delegated Location Receiver
extension SkiTrack: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        for newlocation in locations {
            let howRecent = newlocation.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow

            guard newlocation.horizontalAccuracy < 15 && abs(howRecent) < 5 else {
                print("Location Discarded: \(dump(newlocation))")
                continue
            }

            self.receiveUpdate(newLocation: newlocation)
        }

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError: Error) {
        print(Error.self)
    }

}
```

My thought was to change the above class into some kind of 'Data Manager' which just manages a simple class that i create, store and retrieve from realm. Is that the approach that i should use with Realm or should i just convert my 'all in one' class into a Realm object?

I'm coming from a SQL background so get classic database models and this is an iteration of an app which used SQLite for data storage in the past. I just don't get the way i'd implement it in realm.

Really appreciate any advice and guidance.

Comment: The question is a bit broad as generally speaking, that model can certainly be used as a Realm object. There are a few adjustments and a couple of logic things to think through but for example `var speed = Speed()` is fine as a Realm property `@objc dynamic var speed: Speed!` as along as Speed is a Realm object (or a primitive) that you also want persisted. So start small; craft a Realm object `class SkiTrack: Object` and then start with the first three properties. Keep adding properties until you run into an issue and then loop us in so we can take a look a the specific problem.

Comment: Thanks Jay, i guess i was looking for some forward clarification of the approach rather than trying and become stuck in a model which wouldn't fully function! I'll give it a go and see how i get on, thanks for the confirmation!